# Is there a wavelength of electromagnetic radiation that can penetrate iron but reflect off iron oxides?

Tags: optics, visible-light, x-rays

We can see corrosion or rust because visible light travels through air reflects off the material back through the air and into our eyes. But I am wondering if you could see the corrosion through on the other side of material. Obviously visible light would not work because it cannot penetrate the iron substrate. From my understanding ultraviolet would reflect off the metal just as visible light would, but x-rays would transmit though everything.

So is there such a wavelength that can accomplish this? Transmit through iron and reflect off iron oxides. The idea is "see" corrosion using equipment only on the non corroded side of the material.

Comment: Penetration in metals can happen with Xrays and gamma rays, very high frequency electromagnetic radiation. At those energies the EM radiation interacts as photon-atom interactions for x-rays and even gamma-nucleus. The difference between atoms of iron and complexes of rust exists in the fact that rust has oxygen atoms. In principle one could detect excitations from oxygen, but if the back surface is not accessible, I do not know how much back scattering could be detectable at the level of seeing absorption lines. It needs an expert in solid state andx-rays to give an answer.